# How to solve the maximum value of following expression with respect to some conditions.

Tags: inequality

There are three positive real numbers  $a,b,c$. 
They meet the following conditions：

$1.$ $a+b+c=2n-2$, $n (\geq4)$ is a positive integer ;

$2$. $0<c\leq b \leq a<n$ .

I'd like to know whether $e^a+e^b+e^c$ has some good sharp upper bounds. Any idea is good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note $x \mapsto e^x$ is convex.  So Jensen’s inequality gives you a minimum for what you seek, and with Karamata’s inequality you get a supremum of $e^n+e^{n-2}+1$as $(n, n-2, 0) \succ (a, b, c)$.

Comment: thank you for  your suggestion. It is one of very nice bound for me.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the first constraint we end up with the task to minimize
$$
\mathcal{F}=e^a+e^b+e^{2n-2-a-b}
$$
which has a critical point at
$$
\nabla \mathcal{F}=(-e^{2n-2-a-b}+e^b,-e^{2n-2-a-b}+e^c)^T=0
$$
which leads to $a=b=c=\frac{2n-2}{3}$, which lies in the region specified by constraints (2.). If we then compute the Hessian matrix for $\mathcal{F}$ see directly that it is positive definit by determinant criterion.
Therefore $\mathcal{F}$ is convex and has an isolated minimum attained at the critical point which leads to the inequality
$$
e^a+e^b+e^c\geq3e^\frac{2n-2}{3}.
$$

Comment: Thanks May be it is good for find minimal vulue.